# Separate properties for a shared spring library contained inside a spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I created a shared library in spring that I deploy as an artifact in an artifactory. I use this shared library artifact in another spring boot application as a pom dependency. Shared library has it's own properties files under src/main/resources
I am having problems with the following:

When I try to load the spring boot application, it is not able to load the properties for the shared library and expects all the properties shared library needs in the outer spring boot application. How can fix this and have shared library always read its own properties file ?

Answer (score 0):

Use @PropertySource annotation to provide the two sources for your app:

```
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:yourSharedLib.properties"),
        @PropertySource("classpath:youApp.properties")
    })
```

Comment: where do i need to provide this ? in the shared library ? Properties in shared library are used at multiple places.

Comment: In you app config, not the child library

Comment: Isnt' there a way to keep child app decoupled from the main app and let it decide that it wants to use its own properties ? the way you suggest, config for parent app will need to have a lot of information about the child app.